# How to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch with Model and EF entity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, json-patch

I have the following method in my ASP.NET Core Web API. It's using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch` for patching:

```
[HttpPatch]
public IActionResult PatchCustomer([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<CustomerModel> patchDoc)
{
    if (patchDoc != null)
    {
        var customerEntity = _dbContext.Customers.Where(x=>x.CustomerID == id);

        // the ApplyTo() method below throws compilation error because of type mismatch
        patchDoc.ApplyTo(customerEntity, ModelState);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
          
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

I could fix the error by changing the method parameter to type `JsonPatchDocument<Customer>` where `Customer` in an entity. However, I don't want to expose entity to the API method. The `CustomerModel` type has only certain properties that caller can update so it make sense to use `CustomerModel` as parameter to minimize the risk of caller accidentally updating some other property.

How to update `Customer` entity based on `JsonPatchDocument` here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Automapper` to map `CustomerModel` to the `Customer` entity, and then apply `JsonPatchDocument`.Or use Linq to query to map the attributes of the `Customer` entity to the attributes of the `CustomerModel` model object. Then apply `JsonPatchDocument` to `CustomerModel`, and update the modified attribute value to the physical object. You can refer to the following examples:

My Customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

My CusterModel:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }

     public string Phone {  get; set; }
}
```

My method (useAutomapper):

```
    [HttpPatch]
    public IActionResult PatchCustomer([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<CustomerModel> patchDoc, int id)
    {
        if (patchDoc != null)
        {
            var customerEntity = _dbContext.Customers
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

            if (customerEntity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var customerModel = _mapper.Map<CustomerModel>(customerEntity); 

            patchDoc.ApplyTo(customerModel, ModelState);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            _mapper.Map(customerModel, customerEntity); 

            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

The entity that needs to be mapped:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>(); 
        CreateMap<CustomerModel, Customer>(); 
    }
}
```

In program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
```

Use Linq query(It should be noted that this method requires the attribute name and the type completely matching):

```
[HttpPatch]
public IActionResult PatchCustomer([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<CustomerModel> patchDoc, int id)
{
     if (patchDoc != null)
     {
         var customerEntity = _dbContext.Customers
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

         if (customerEntity == null)
         {
             return NotFound();
         }

         var customerModel = new CustomerModel
         {
             Name = customerEntity.Name,
             Email = customerEntity.Email,
             Phone =customerEntity.Phone,
         };

         patchDoc.ApplyTo(customerModel, ModelState);

         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             return BadRequest(ModelState);
         }
         customerEntity.Name = customerModel.Name;
         customerEntity.Email = customerModel.Email;
         customerEntity.Phone = customerModel.Phone;
         _dbContext.SaveChanges();

         return Ok();
     }
     else
     {
         return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }
}
```